# Any difference is how much memory is used by REDIS

Tags: redis

Imagine these two scenarios for REDIS-SERVER:

(A)redis-cli> set "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com" "1"

(B)redis-cli> setbit "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com" 1 1

If 1 million different keys are stored with customer name/email. 
Use case is that i would like to check if record exists, 
so 
in case of (A)

redis-cli> get "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com"

reply from REDIS would be> 1

in case of (B)

redis-cli> getbit "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com" 1

reply from REDIS would be> 1

Question:

Will there be any difference in the amount of memory used by REDIS if all one million key/value pairs are kept in memory for query?

Comment: If you are using Redis 4, you can check the memory usage differences between the two options. `MEMORY USAGE <key>` will output the # of bytes used to store the key and its value.

Answer (score 2):

You should use *solution A*. It's more meaningful, and costs less memory, since Redis has special encoding for small integers. In your case, the value part, i.e. *"1"*, won't cost extra memory.

Also, another solution is to use a `SET` to save these name/email pairs: use `SADD name-email "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com"` to add record, and use `SISMEMBER name-email "firstname lastname.AT.emailaddress.dot.com"` to check the existence.

Comment: Doesn't Redis convert integers to strings? And would argue against using one set if using a Redis cluster, since it will hit one shard.

Comment: 1. Redis has special encoding for small integers, i.e. [0, 10000). These small integers' objects are ref-counted. So no matter how many small integers you have, they won't cost extra memory. 2. Yes, if OP works on cluster, `SET` is NOT the best solution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about #1! Thanks =)